# Sorting with stream.sorted() in Java

Tags: java, sorting, java-stream, comparator

I have e.g list of elemenets like sg-1, sg-5, sg-13, sg-6 and etc and i need sort them by numbers.
The part of my code is:

```
}).map(c -> {
                System.out.println(c);
                return c;
            }).distinct()
            .sorted((c1, c2) -> c1.substring(c1.indexOf("-"), c1.length())
                    .compareTo(c2.substring(c2.indexOf("-"), c2.length())))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

system out prints 
sg-1
sg-1
sg-1
sg-9
sg-1
sg-4
sg-15
sg-1
sg-1
sg-1
sg-1

But in the end I get [sg-1, sg-15, sg-4, sg-9] however it has to be [sg-1, sg-4, sg-9, sg-15]
How to sort them, please help my :)

Comment: c1.substring(c1.indexOf("-"), c1.length()) return a value with the dash(-) which is considered as a negative number. For example, your code will return -1, -5 , -13 instead of 1,5,13, You could use c1.substring(c1.indexOf("-") + 1, c1.length()) to skip the dash (-). I dont understand why you are using map.

Comment: So, yeah, you are right, However I have tried to use .sorted((c1, c2) -> c1.substring(c1.indexOf("-") + 1, c1.length())
                        .compareTo(c2.substring(c2.indexOf("-") + 1, c2.length())))
                .collect(Collectors.toList()); But it doesen't work. May be "comparedTo" cannot correctly sort the numbers, if they are string not int or integer ?

Answer (score 4):

The first thing you're doing wrong is that you're *comparing strings lexicographically* and not integers as you might be expecting.

Second, even if you were to convert `c1.substring(c1.indexOf("-"), c1.length())` to integer and then compare you'll still get incorrect results.

why is that?

This is because `c1.substring(c1.indexOf("-"), c1.length())`, the first argument to substring is *inclusive* , this means you'll always extract negative numbers.

Solution:

1. You'll actually need to compare integers as opposed to strings.
2. The first argument to substring should actually be `c1.indexOf("-") + 1` to start after the "-".

---

```
List<String> result = list.stream()
                .distinct()
                .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(s -> 
                    Integer.parseInt(s.substring(s.indexOf("-") + 1, s.length()))))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

As an aside, don't use `map` to perform debugging work, instead utilise [peek](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#peek-java.util.function.Consumer-).

```
List<String> result = list.stream()
                 .peek(System.out::println)
                 .distinct()
                 .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(s -> 
                     Integer.parseInt(s.substring(s.indexOf("-") + 1, s.length()))))
                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Note that there is a single-argument version of `substring` which already implies `length()` as second parameter. Further, if you can preclude leading zeros, you can stay with string comparison when you just prepend a length comparison: `Comparator.comparingInt((String s) -> s.length()-s.indexOf("-"))    .thenComparing(s -> s.substring(s.indexOf("-")+1))`

Comment: @Holger good shout! completely forgot about that overload at the time of writing and thanks to the following suggestion as well. appreciated as always.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this out

```
List<String> result = list.stream().distinct().sorted((a1,a2)->{
        return Integer.compare(Integer.parseInt(a1.split("-")[1]), Integer.parseInt(a2.split("-")[1]));
    }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: It works, but could you explain me, what do these [1] mean ? and why with my code I do not get the sorted result?

Comment: The piece of code splits the individual strings considering the dash(-). It then takes the second part of the string that is the numbers at the end. For "sg-1" is split it into "sg" and "1". It takes the number and converts to an integer and compares it. Hope this helps.

Comment: avoid using raw types. it's _much_ better to utilise generics.

Comment: Also, your current approach is inefficient as it creates two array objects for each time the function to `sorted` is invoked and this can be avoided.